# sample/starter code to test for TRUSTe password requirements

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-policy

Considering its a requirement for Truste certification I figure that the code to test for a password meeting Truste's password strength requirements has been written more than a few times. I was wondering if anyone has ever shared a version written in NodeJS?

Something like was done for the OWASP password standards

https://www.npmjs.com/package/owasp-password-strength-test

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Implement_Proper_Password_Strength_Controls